# when to add and remove self from SKPaymentQueue.default when dealing with IAP

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have IAP working inside my app but can't help but to feel I'm doing something wrong with when to call. When should I be calling these methods?

`SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)` and when to call
`SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)`

Thanks guys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## 1. Adding observer

You should add an observer to the queue *as soon as possible*. Somewhere in your `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` function in your app delegate.

Mentioned in the `add(_:)` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506042-add):

> Your application should add an observer to the payment queue during
>   application initialization.

Your app should basically **always** be ready to process a transaction and mark it as finished¹. Because any unhandled transactions are added back to the queue until you have handled them:

> **Make sure that the observer is ready to handle a
>   transaction at any time**, not just after you add a transaction to the
>   queue. [...] if your app fails to mark a transaction as finished,
>   StoreKit calls the observer every time your app is launched until the
>   transaction is properly finished.

## 2. Removing observer

There is no reason to remove yourself as observer during normal app use. As you should *always* be able to process any incoming transactions.

That means you should remove yourself *as late as possible*. The best place for that is in the `applicationWillTerminate(_:)` [function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate) in the app delegate:

> This method lets your app know that it is about to be terminated and
>   purged from memory entirely. You should **use this method to perform
>   any final clean-up tasks** for your app [...]

Removing as observer is not as explicitly talked about in Apple's documentation, but you can see it in a code snippet under *listing 2* in their [In-App Purchase Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2387/_index.html) tech note:

```swift
// Called when the application is about to terminate.
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
   // Remove the observer.
   SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(your_observer)
}
```

---

### Useful links

- [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW4)
- [In-App Purchase Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2387/_index.html)

---

¹ : only [mark a transaction finished](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506003-finishtransaction) when it makes *sense*, whatever that means for your app:

> Your application should call `finishTransaction:` only after it has
>   **successfully processed the transaction and unlocked the functionality**
>   purchased by the user

Comment: Can "your_observer" be a UIViewController(in AppDelegate -> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)? Lets say the view controller is called TheViewWhereTheyBuy. How can one use SKPaymentQueue.default().add(TheViewWhereTheyBuy)?